# Order of the pole of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^4-z^2}$ at 0

Tags: complex-analysis

I have problems finding order of the pole at $z=0$

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^4-z^2}$$

I got expansion around $0$:
$$ f(z)=-\frac{1}{z^2}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}z^{2n} $$

So the $C_{-2}$ is the biggest negative power of z, therefore i think the order should be 2 but because only even powers of z exist, there is no $C_{-1}$. Is the order 2 anyway?
Also what is $Res(f;0)$? I wrote down at class that when there are only even powers $Res(f;0)=0$. Why is that so?

Comment: What's the order of the zero of $z^4-z^2$ at $z=0$?

Comment: Is it really that simple? Just order of denominator, and it doesn't matter that $C_{-1}$ doesn't exist?

Comment: A complex function $f(z)/g(z)$ has a pole at $z_0$ of order $M$ if and only if its reciprocal $g(z)/f(z)$ has a zero at $z_0$ of order $M$.

Comment: Thank you! I've never seen that definition, we used the one that says that the order of the pole is the first negative potention "from the left". What is with the residuum

Answer (score 1):

Since
$$
\lim_{z\to0}z^2f(z)=
\lim_{z\to0}\frac{1}{z^2-1}=-1\ne0
$$
the function $z^2f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $0$ and the extended function has no zero at $0$. Its Taylor expansion is then
$$
z^2f(z)=-1+a_1z+a_2z^2+\dotsb
$$
and $f$ has a pole of order $2$ at $0$.

This generalizes to

> The point $z_0$ is a pole of order $m$ for $f$ holomorphic in a punctured neighborhood of $z_0$ if and only if
>   $$\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)^mf(z)$$
>   exists and is finite and nonzero.

Your method is also good; finding the explicit Laurent expansion also tells you that the residue at $0$ is $0$. On the other hand, the function is even (that is, $f(-z)=f(z)$) so the Laurent expansion has no term of odd degree. The residue is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion.